# Optimize SQL subquery for statistics

Tags: mysql, sql, bigdata

I created a simple statistics tool for our user PCs. It records every 5 minutes the state of all of our PCs. And a little frontend gives me a usage chart:
[image]

Now with growing data the SQL queries are getting slower and slower and I'm searching a way to optimize it.

This is the structure. As you can see, the table "usage" contains about 6 million records and it uses MySQL InnoDB:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `usage` (
`id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `host_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `time` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `state` enum('LinuxTU','LinuxExt','View','Browser','Idle','Offline') CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Offline'
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5963366 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

ALTER TABLE `usage`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`), ADD KEY `host_id` (`host_id`), ADD KEY `time` (`time`);

ALTER TABLE `usage`
MODIFY `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=5963366;
```

The following query takes about 7 seconds to execute. It is the query that gives the data to the screenshot.

```sql
/* create pivot table */
SELECT `time`,
    SUM(IF(state='LinuxTU', statecount, 0)) AS LinuxTU,
    SUM(IF(state='LinuxExt', statecount, 0)) AS LinuxExt,
    SUM(IF(state='View', statecount, 0)) AS View,
    SUM(IF(state='Browser', statecount, 0)) AS Browser
FROM (
    /* get data from last 24h grouped by state */
    SELECT `time`, `state`, COUNT(`state`) statecount
    FROM `usage` u
    /* group by time to get every 5 minutes
       group by state to get the state counter */
    GROUP BY `time`, `state`
    HAVING `time` > 1441271078 AND `time` < 1441357478
) AS s
GROUP BY `time`
ORDER BY `time` ASC
```

I don't know how to optimize it. Is there something I missed? Or do I need to reorganize the structure? Any Hint?

Answer (score 2):

In addition to moving the `time` comparison into a `where` clause, you can get rid of the subquery entirely:

```
/* create pivot table */
SELECT `time`,
       SUM(state = 'LinuxTU') AS LinuxTU,
       SUM(state = 'LinuxExt') AS LinuxExt,
       SUM(state = 'View') AS View,
       SUM(state = 'Browser') AS Browser
FROM usage u
WHERE `time` > 1441271078 AND `time` < 1441357478
GROUP BY `time`
ORDER BY `time` ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is on the last

```
GROUP BY `time`
ORDER BY `time` ASC
```

because of the subquery your indexes are gone. So, you should find a way to eliminate that.

Do you also have the option to make some processing in the programming language ? Just make the inner select + the variables without sum from the outer select, also add the order and then make the processing in the programming language.

Or must you write this in a query ?

Comment: I could eliminate the pivot query by changing the table from one ENUM field to multiple state fields (like LinuxTU=0,LinuxExt=1). But I thought multiple fields making it inflexible and perhaps incosistent (for example: LinuxTU=1 and LinuxExt=1). Actually the frontend uses the data as it is. So every query outputs thte needed data.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the bottleneck. The problem is the inner query. HAVING seems to be much slower than WHERE. So I tried some different queries and now I got this result:

**Takes 7 seconds:**

```sql
SELECT `time`, `state`, COUNT(`state`) statecount
FROM `usage` u
GROUP BY `time`, `state`
HAVING `time` > 1441271078 AND `time` < 1441357478
```

**Takes 0.1 seconds:**

```sql
SELECT `time`, `state`, COUNT(`state`) `statecount`
FROM `usage` u
WHERE `time` > 1441271078 AND `time` < 1441357478
GROUP BY `time`, `state`
```

And gives me the same result. The frontend is now much faster.